# HttpClient POST

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-4.5

I'm using some POST requests in my project until when I came across a form with

> onsubmit="return false;"

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
...
</form>
```

This form is submitted by a javascript onclick button function.

All the other request I'm doing are working correctly, but not this one and I strongly believe the onsubmit false is the cause.

Is there anyway to get around this?

**EDIT (Complement) **

thats the POST request

```
        FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "b")

        });
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> post = client.PostAsync(url, formContent);
        post.Wait();
        Task<string> contents = post.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        contents.Wait();
```

Comment: remove return false with the method that you want to execute

Comment: Does the onclick method actually execute? Have you stepped through the code in js debugger in the browser?

Comment: @AtulChaudhary Not sure how I can remove the return false.

Comment: @berniefitz The code does execute in browser, if I click on the submit button. But not when I do the POST request. I believe thats because the request tries to submit the form, but the form is only submited by the onclick js function

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
...
</form>
```

with

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="urlendpointurl" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit to me">
</form>
```

In typical Asp.Net MVC app ur urlendpointurl will be like "~/Home/Save"

Comment: I wish it was that easy.. But unfortunatelly I can't change the page html

Comment: can you execute javascript on html page?

Comment: This page I'm trying to do this POST request is not under my control. That's why I can't change it's html or javascript content. And I'm also not using any automation like Selenium to force a click on the button. I have to send that form and get the response using the HttpClient. Unless you can tell me another alternative. Thanks for helping